# Is there a way to 'dequeue' a `require_once` entry?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, require

I am currently working on a WordPress website, which has a Parent and Child Theme.

The Parent Theme is outputting the following statement, at the top of the WordPress Dashboard:

> This theme requires the following plugins: Plugin A, Plugin B, Plugin C etc

Triggering this output, is the following code, within the Parent Theme's `functions.php` file:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/plugins/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
```

Is there a way I could disable this, via the Child Theme's `functions.php`?  Sure, I could comment it out within the Parent Theme, but this could get overridden during a future update.  I did try to copy the entry, into the Child Theme's `functions.php`, then comment it out there, but that did not work.

**Latest Effort**

1. I went into the WordPress Dashboard, where I copied the notification message prefix:

> This theme requires the following plugins:

2. I then went into the file located within `get_template_directory() . '/inc/plugins/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php'`, where I found the above notification prefix, located within the `do_action( 'tgmpa_register' );` function.
3. I then located the `add_action` for the `do_action( 'tgmpa_register' );` within the   `/inc/functions/tgm-functions.php` directory.
4. I then headed into the Child Theme, and duplicated the above folder hierarchy.
5. I then commented out both `add_action` and `do_action`, within their respective files as well as entering `remove_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'register_required_plugins', 999 );` into the Child's `functions.php` file.

Unfortunately, neither of the above work.  I take it, that this is because the Parent Directory `parent_theme/inc` has priority over the Child Directory `child_theme/inc`?  If so, is there a way to change this?

Comment: If you are simply trying to hide the notification, you could add a CSS hack to the admin dashboard to target this message and prevent it from being displayed. Otherwise, not sure there is much you can do. The parents functions file will always load. You could try remove_action() to prevent the notification as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Whilst CSS is an option, I was hoping to achieve this on the server side of things.